# How to make sidebar with 100% height and fixed position

Tags: html, css

I want `100% height` using css and with position fixed please advice me.

[image]

Comment: show us your code as well

Comment: show your code and describe your problem properly!

Comment: Done samir Thanks for view :)

Comment: done Sanjeev thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please look at that. [There](http://codepen.io/snave/pen/GjJJYv) is a working version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer how to get the layout you wanna achieve.

**HTML**

```
<div class="long-nav">
<ul>
    <li>Deals &amp; Offer</li>
    <li>Deals &amp; Offer</li>
    <li>Deals &amp; Offer</li>
    <li>Deals &amp; Offer</li>
    <li>Deals &amp; Offer</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
  list-style:none;
  padding:20px 10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

.long-nav{
  width:30%;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dfo7vn6v/)